# Imported module onto pycharm but still have a ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, import, module, pycharm

import text2emotion as te

[image]

I have it installed on pycharm and I imported it but I get the error. IS there something wrong with the path? I am not too sure what to do.

```
    import text2emotion as te
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'text2emotion'
```

Comment: what interpreter are you using to run the code? probably pycharm has created a virtual environment for your project

Answer (score 1):

make sure your pycharm environment is set to the proper interpreter, you can choose it at the bottom right of your IDE.
or that you installed text2emotion in the proper python version for your interpreter

if both of these are correct, I would try to reinstall the module, or re-assign the environment

Answer (score 1):

It's probably a problem with the interpreter you are using. As you mentioned, the interpreter which Pycharm using has already installed text2emotion.

So maybe you are running your code outside of Pycharm (eg: through external commandline/terminal, NOT the terminal integrated in Pycharm). I suggest you should run it within Pycharm, or make sure that you run your code with the exact interpreter Pycharm using.